# How to force direct download srt file instead of opening in the window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, nginx

I have a website for translating srt files and files are saved in the database with option for downloading the srt files (you can check that by visiting this [page](https://translatesubtitles.com/details.php?id=6593) and click "Download subtitle" ) but I have a problem :

Visitors can download the srt file clicking on the button "Download subtitle" but when I copy link location of that srt file and add it on the browser url , I get page with opened srt file instead of download it , is there anything I can do to fix this, so when I share that url of the srt file that download start instantly instead of opening file in the browser window? Code for the buttton

`<a href="uploads_iota/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>.srt" target='_blank' class="btn btn-primary" download>Download Subtitle</a>`

Comment: No, that's the way it was designed to work. If you want to prevent the user from being able to copy/paste the link you can create a custom onClick handler.

Comment: We did not understand each other my friend, my intention is not to hide the url link, I just want that when visitors copy the URL from the "Download subtitle" button and visit the URL via browser to start downloading the srt file and not to open that srt file in the broswer window.

Comment: You can make that happen if you have control over the HTML at the target URL. Do you? If you do not have control over the files being served at the target URL, then it's not possible. I recommend preventing the user from ever being able to land in that state, as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes I have control over the HMTL at the target URL, so what can I do then?